# Kafka consumer with TLS. Performance issue

Tags: performance, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, handshake

In my application I have kafka configured to work with TLS, so I have few consumers which each time polling the new messages from the broker.

Problem is that if I have 5 consumers and each is performing poll for each 100 ms, I have a tones of SSLHandshakes.

I aware about "session resumption" that I used to use in web services. My question:

**Is there any possibility to say to the kafka consumer that it doesn't need to perform handshake each time, and use symmetric key that was created during the first handshake?**

Answer (score 0):

TLS Handshake is only performed when creating the connection. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake

Kafka Consumers keep the connection alive between polls, so each Consumer only performs a TLS Handshake once, to each broker it's using, at startup.

Comment: I also thought like that. However in debug I see that it is performing handshake over and over again.

@Mickael Maison, are you sure? Where you have found info that consumer keep the connetion alive between pools?

Comment: Can you paste the log where you see many handshakes? The Network section in the Kafka protocol documentation (http://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_network) covers how connections are made and maintained.